# How to integrate code repository hosted on gerrit to jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit

My Project code is hosted on git and gerrit. I want to integrate gerrit with jenkins. when I enter the SSH path or HTTP path in Source Code Management section (Jenkins) I get below error

ERROR:

Started by timer
Building on master in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
[WS-CLEANUP] Done
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository http://sushma@10.1.1.200:29418/Test_Automation HEAD

> git init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo # timeout=10
>   Fetching upstream changes from http://sushma@10.1.1.200:29418/Test_Automation HEAD
>   git --version # timeout=10
>   using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
>   git fetch --tags --progress http://sushma@10.1.1.200:29418/Test_Automation HEAD +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>   ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
>   ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress http://sushma@10.1.1.200:29418/Test_Automation HEAD +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 143:
>   stdout: 
>   stderr: 
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2016)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1735)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:420)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:629)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1146)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1186)
>       at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
>       at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
>       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1798)
>       at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
>   ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
>   Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

You're cloning from 29418 port using http. Change the repository URL to:

```
ssh://sushma@10.1.1.200:29418/Test_Automation
```

Or:

```
http://sushma@10.1.1.200/Test_Automation
```

If you have doubts about the correct repository URL to use at the "git clone" command at:

- Go to Gerrit server web interface
- Click on ***Projects*** > ***List***
- Search for the Test_Automation project
- Click on the project name
- Click on ***General*** tab
- Look at the http and ssh "git clone" command

Comment: Below is the clone command from gerrit.                                                                     
git clone http://sushma@10.1.1.200:8080/Test_Automation

Comment: I get below error when i integrate with jenkins with above URL                                            Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h ssh://sushma@10.1.1.200:29418/Test_Automation HEAD" returned status code 128:stdout: stderr: Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository.Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.